# How to find string in List<TextView> android

Tags: java, android

I have a list "allPay" of type TextView. I need to find a string say, "abc" in this list. I have used "contains()" to find a string from this list but I always get "false" as answer even if the list contains this string.

Here's the code:

```
TextView tv_method_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_method_name);
tv_method_name.setText("abc");
tv_method_name.setText("abcde");

List<TextView> allPay = new ArrayList<TextView>();

allpay.add(tv_method_name);
String str = "abc";
System.out.println("====allpay contains string?:" +     
allPay.contains("abc"));
```

result:

====allpay contains string?: false

Comment: contains in work on object addresses instead of object values so you will need to make a helper function to loop through and find the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate through the List of Textviews using a for loop or for each loop in order to check the text. Just use this method:

```
boolean listContains(List<TextView> txtViews, String textToCheck) {
    for (TextView txtView : txtViews) {
        if (txtView.getText().toString.contains(textToCheck)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then just use:

```
if (listContains(allPay, "abc")) {
    //"abc" is contained within one of the lists, do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Solved my problem :)

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this:

```
allPay.contains("abc"));
```

because the method contains is searching objects... and not the content of the objects...

so you are asking if a list of TextViews contains a String.. and is not correct

You can search on it iterating the list on a loop and using the [String#indexOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) method

```
List<String> allPay = new ArrayList<String>();

allpay.add(tv_method_name);
allpay.add(tv_method_name);
allpay.add(tv_method_name);
allpay.add(tv_method_name);
allpay.add(tv_method_name);
for (TextView tv : allPay) {
    if (tv.getText.toString().indexOf("abc")!=-1) {
        System.out.println("Found!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: `indexOf == any *abc*` , contains method by itself using `indexof` see String Class .

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this part.

```
TextView tv_method_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_method_name);
tv_method_name.setText("abc");
tv_method_name.setText("abcde");
```

The tv_method_name is modified twice, for this reason the last value in the variable is "abcde", when you are looking at the list for the value "abc", the method "Contains" returns "false" because this object not exists.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of TextView objects and you are searching for a String. That won't work.

Try the following:

```
String yourText = "abc";
for(TextView tv: allPlay){
   if(tv!=null && tv.getText()!=null && tv.getText().toString().contains(yourText)){
       Log.d(TAG,"found:" + true);
   }
}
```